# Emspripten gives a multiple async error, while one call isn't async

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

From JS I pass a callback to C++. C++ calls this JS callback asynchronously.

- If the JS callback calls a synchronous function from C++, it works fine.
- If the JS callback calls an asynchronous function, it works fine.
- If I combine these two calls, it crashes. Even if I use `await`.

The error is: `RuntimeError: Aborted(Assertion failed: Cannot have multiple async operations in flight at once)`
I've not come across anyone who had this error under these circumstances.

C++:

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void async_func(emscripten::val func) { func().await(); }
void sync_func() {}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(async_test)
{
    emscripten::function("async_func", &async_func);
    emscripten::function("sync_func", &sync_func);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

JS:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="./out/build/em-x64-debug/async_test.js"></script>
        <script>
            async function async_cb(){
                // These lines work individually, but break when used simultaneously.
                await fetch('./test.txt')
                Module.sync_func()
            }

            Module['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {
                Module.async_func(async_cb)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how this can be solved and how you can still call C++ functions after the asynchronous fetch? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a shotgun reply, but I will say that Asyncify is very opaque about what it is doing, and the lack of ability to control whether it is wrapping Embind calls can be virtually impossible to cope with in a complex project. My best suggestion would be to not use Asyncify in your project, unless it's an existing codebase that is tied to Asyncify.

I will also say that there's a neat, but not at all future-proof, way to make Asyncify stop wrapping Embind functions:

```
EM_ASM(
    Asyncify.whenDone = () => Promise.resolve();
);
```

This is likely too ham fisted for most applications though.